# Prepopulate Values of Edit Form from Table Selection

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am trying to create an Edit for that allows the user to scroll through a table and click a button existing in each row to edit the data within a modal.

The issue that I am running into is when I try to prepopulate the form with the existing values. How would I convert the EditCommunicationsForm below to display the current values of the row that you selected edit for? I know I can make the initial value a default value like "Testing" but I am not quite sure how to tell it to say "grab the project field from the row that you selected"

What I want to do is ID = {{ communications.id }} for my table, but obviously that's wrong since it's half HTML. I need some sort of variable to change that definition for each row

views

```
def communications(request):
    comms_list = Communications.objects.order_by('id')
    if request.method == "POST":
        new_form = CommunicationsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        edit_form = EditCommunicationsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:7000/polls/communications/',{"new_form":new_form,"edit_form":edit_form,'comms_list':comms_list})
    else:
        comms = Communications.objects.get(id=1)
        new_form = CommunicationsForm()
        edit_form = EditCommunicationsForm(instance=comms)

        query = request.GET.get('search')
        if query:
            postresult = Communications.objects.filter(id__contains=query)
            comms_list = postresult
        else:
            comms_list = Communications.objects.order_by('id')

        return render(request,'polls/communications.html',{"new_form":new_form,"edit_form":edit_form,'comms_list':comms_list})
```

forms

```
class CommunicationsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Communications
        fields = "__all__"

        widgets = {
            'project':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Enter your Project Name'}),
            'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Enter a short Title'}),
            'intent':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control','height':'50px','placeholder':'Describe the intent and desired outcome of the communication'}),
            'date':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Select a Date'}),
            'channel':forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'content_type':forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Select a Content Type'}),
            'audience':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Enter the Audience(s)'}),
            'status':forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Select the Status'}),
            }

class EditCommunicationsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Communications
        fields = "__all__"

        widgets = {
            'project':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','initial':'Project 123'}),
            'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Enter a short Title'}),
            'intent':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control','height':'50px','placeholder':'Describe the intent and desired outcome of the communication'}),
            'date':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Select a Date'}),
            'channel':forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'content_type':forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Select a Content Type'}),
            'audience':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Enter the Audience(s)'}),
            'status':forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Select the Status'}),
            }
```

html

```
<tbody>
    {% for communications in comms_list %}
    <tr style="font-family: Graphik;font-size: 12px">
        <td>{{ communications.id }}</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm badge-pill" style="font-size: 11px; width:60px" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit">Edit</button></td>
        <td>{{ communications.project }}</td>
        <td>{{ communications.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ communications.intent }}</td>
        <td style="width:150px">{{ communications.date }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>

<!--Edit Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Update Item</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{edit_form}}
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" value="update" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot: I selected row 2, which should yield CIT MVP, but instead it's AAA because I had initial={"project":"AAA"}
[image]

Comment: are you still looking for answer ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem right, you want to populate existing data for multiple rows in same modal. A little bit of Javascript can help you here.

1. Set data in javascript dictionary
   `let dict = {{json_data_from_views}};`
   (wrap it in document.ready() function)
   Note that Id of data will be key
2. pass this key in onclick function in every edit button.
   `onclick="populate_modal("{{communications.id}}")`
   So now if we click edit button with id = 1, we can fetch the data for this id from JS dictionary and set it in modal fields.
3. populate_modal() function
   `function populate_modal(id){   $("#modal_field").val(dict[id]['project']);   }`

One Suggestion though. Since you would want to modify multiple rows, try using ajax calls.